# Acumatica. Error during updating the Customer's Credit Limit

Tags: api, acumatica

Could you help me with the following question?

I try to update the Customer Credit Limit in Acumatica:

**Request:**

```html
    PUT https://{Base_URL}/Customer?$select=CreditVerificationRules&$filter=CustomerID%20eq%20'0e31e8a5-08e3-ea11-a828-000d3ab2c384'

{
"CreditVerificationRules": {
"CreditLimit": {
"value": 1234.0
}
}
}
```

But I receive the following error:

```html
Response: {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Syntax error: character '%' is not valid at position 10 in 'CustomerID%20eq%20'0e31e8a5-08e3-ea11-a828-000d3ab2c384'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the html encoding.  I.e.  CustomerID eq '0e31e8a5-08e3-ea11-a828-000d3ab2c384'  FYI, if this was an instance where you needed html encoding, then you should have encoded the ' symbol as well.

Comment: Patrick, we tried but received an error

Response: {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Inserting  'Customer' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors.\nLegalName: 'Legal Name' cannot be empty.\nPrepaymentAcctID: Account 22100 is not a control account. Please select an account configured as a control account for AR.\nAcctName: 'Customer Name' cannot be empty.\nMailDunningLetters: Email address must be specified if 'Send Dunning Letters by Email' option is activated

Comment: What else could be a mistake?

Comment: The Customer doesn't have the following properties:
LegalName, PrepaymentAcctID

Comment: This message implies that it is trying to create a new record.  I can tell you that Customer ID is not a GUID, i think you're sending the wrong value.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your prompt reply.
I am going to rectify my request according to your recommendations.

Comment: We tried:
https://{BASE_URL}/17.200.001/Customer/27123b2c-d87f-e411-beca-00b56d0561c2

But received an error once again:

Response: {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: Invalid uri structure","exceptionType":"System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException","stackTrace":"

What is the reason?

Comment: That value is not a valid CustomerID

Comment: On UI, in Acumatica, I see Customer ID and Customer Name
For Example:

Customer ID = ABARTENDE.
Customer Name = USA School.

As I understood, we should use ABARTENDE instead of 27123b2c-d87f-e411-beca-00b56d0561c2.

Is it correct?

Comment: I tried.
Everything is working now.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Sounds good, if you mark this as answered, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Hello Patrick,

Sure, I will make it.

Patrick, could you help me with the following question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66128387/receiving-the-customer-summary