# Receiving the Customer Summary

Tags: acumatica, erp

I hope things are going well.

Could you please help me with the following question.

Acumatica has the Customer Summary module. Link to the description - https://help-2017r2.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=4d224cd8-6553-4930-872b-d667ddff891e

I want to receive all Customers from this summary and their Currency Ending Balance column.

But I cannot find the API to receive these Customers and their Currency Ending Balances.

Could you provide a link to the API?

Of course, if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the Default Endpoint or create a new one and add that page to the endpoint in the way shown below.
[image]
[image]
[image]
You can find the help articles on how to extend the endpoint by [this link](https://help-2020r2.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c450492e-06fe-4563-95c3-efa76975415b).

After adding the entity to the endpoint you can simply do a PUT request and retrieve the data that you need like below:

[image]

Comment: Samvel,

Thank you a lot!
I am going to repeat your solution.

Regards,
Andrew

Comment: Hello Samvel,

Could you please help me with this ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178997/error-once-i-try-to-create-a-payment-via-api?noredirect=1#comment117002570_66178997   ?

I cannot find how I should send the Post Period in the request to create a payment (

Comment: Samvel,

I responded you to the ticket
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178997/error-once-i-try-to-create-a-payment-via-api?noredirect=1#comment117007215_66178997

Comment: Hi Samvel,

Could you help me with the following question?

Where in Acumatica I can see the base currency? I want to change the base currency, but I cannot find the menu where I can do it.
And how I can receive the base currency via API?
Could you provide an example?

Thank you!