# Error once I try to create a payment via API

Tags: api, acumatica

Could you help me with the following question?
I try to create a payment via API.
But, I receive the following error:

> Response: {"message":"The request is invalid.","modelState":{"entity":["The Entity field is required."]}}
> An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Inserting  'CA Transaction' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors.\nFinPeriodID: 'Post Period' cannot be empty.","exceptionType"

I opened the financial year 2021.
Could you please provide an example how to send the Post Period in the request?

Comment: The error indicates that you have not specified a Post Period.  It is not complaining that the period is closed which is what I would expect to see if it was related to needing to open the financial year 2021.  Try populating the Post Period in your API call to see if that moves you forward.

Comment: Could you provide an example hot to add this parameter to the request?

Comment: I do not work with API calls enough to provide an example, but it should mirror how you specify other field values.

Comment: @Andrew please add your request body and url to the question

Comment: {
    "entity": {},
    "parameters": {
         
        "OrderNbr": {"value": "OrderNbr"
        },
        "OrderType": {"value": "OrderType"
        },
        "PaymentMethod": {"value": "PaymentMethod"
        },
        "BranchID": {"value": "BranchID"
        },
        "PaymentRefNbr": {"value": "PaymentRefNbr"
        },
        "PaymentTotal": {"value": "100"
        },

       "PostPeriod": {"value": "02/2021"
        },
    }
}

Comment: Maybe I should use the following?

{
    "entity": {},
    "parameters": {
         
        "OrderNbr": {"value": "OrderNbr"
        },
        "OrderType": {"value": "OrderType"
        },
        "PaymentMethod": {"value": "PaymentMethod"
        },
        "BranchID": {"value": "BranchID"
        },
        "PaymentRefNbr": {"value": "PaymentRefNbr"
        },
        "PaymentTotal": {"value": "100"
        },

        "ApplicationHistory": {
            "PostPeriod": {
               "value": 02/2021
        }
        },     

    }
}

Comment: Method: PUT

 https: //InstanceURl/entity/EndpointName/EndpointVersion/CreatePayments/createPayment

Comment: @Andrew which Endpoint and Version are you using? I don't see this CreatePayments entity under any predefined Endpoint. Is this an extended endpoint? Then which page and action have you mapped to this CreatePayments/CreatePayment entity/action?

Comment: Something I'm already confused.

The endpoint to create a payment in the Receivables -> Payments and Applications/
But, I wanted to create a payment manually and I don't see the PostPeriod field on UI/
So I guess the problem is somewhere else.
Maybe Acumatica changed the request to create a payment?

Comment: I suggest you create the Posting Period by generating the calendar first inside of Acumatica.  Go to "Master Financial Calendar" in Acumatica and create the current calendar year.  Then go to "Manage Financial Periods" and open the periods that you need.